# Serving audio / video / image files to mobile using Google App Engine Mobile Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, mobile, backend, google-cloud-storage

So, I'm new to Google App Engine and I'm trying to use it to setup my mobile backend. 
What I want to do is to be able to put up some songs on the backend and be able to GET those files as a request in my android app. 
I've followed a few steps that I found online:

1) Deployed a backend for my app with a unique ID

Link: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

2) Tried the example app that was provided and was able to connect and send data to my app's backend:

Link: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/

However, I still can't figure out how to do what I want which is to put files on the backend and be able to request them from the app and have them show up (e.g a streaming a song on my app).
I would really appreciate any help here. Again keep in mind that I'm very new to the Google App Engine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MBS is primarily to let you store and access your data in datastore, directly from devices, without necessarily having your own server process.

For a streaming service, you will need to have a server process.
Best way is to store files with full control, is to use BlobStore and use the [BlobReader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) to read and serve in chunks.

More convenient way, but with less control is to store in [cloud-storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/) and serve directly to client with cloud-storage URI, without streaming through your server, in which case, you do not need a server process.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to go with the cloud storage option and it was actually pretty straight forward. thanks for the help Ashish.